# Is it possible to create trigger on selection, for google script in slides?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

Is it possible to create trigger on selection, for google script in slides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) only works on **Google Docs**, **Sheets**, or **Forms** files as per documentation.